# UISplitViewController using delegate to pass a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a Split View Controller for an iPad app.  I'm trying to send a label change to the detailReceiving Controller from the rootSending Controll when a button is pushed.  I've read through tutorials on protocols and came up with the code below.  When I click the button on rootSending, nothing happens to the label on detailReceiving.  Do I have to do something else with a splitViewContoller so that the label will update?  Shouldn't detailReceiving change the label when it receives the message?

rootSending.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol TestDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)tester:(NSString*)testString;
@end

@interface rootSending : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <TestDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

rootSending.m

```
#import "rootSending.h"

@implementation rootSending
@synthesize delegate;
-(void)viewDidLoad{

 }
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

[delegate tester:@"button pressed"];
}

@end
```

detailReceiving.m

```
#import "detailReceiving.h"
#import "rootSending.h"
@interface detailReceiving ()<TestDelegate>{
IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
}
@end
@implementation detailReceiving
-(void)viewDidLoad{
rootSending *obj = [rootSending alloc];
obj.delegate = self ;
}
-(void)tester:(NSString *)testString{
label2.text = testString;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never ever have an alloc without an init! But in this case, even if you did use alloc/init, it still wouldn't work because that just creates a new instance of rootSending, not the one that you have in your split view. You need to get a reference to the one you have, which you can get from the split view controller,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
rootSending *obj = (rootSending *)self.splitViewController.viewControllers.firstObject;
obj.delegate = self;
}
```

After Edit:

If your mate controller is embedded in a navigation controller, then you need to get the navigation controller's topViewController to get your reference.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)self.splitViewController.viewControllers.firstObject;
    xmlListOfItems *obj = (xmlListOfItems *)nav.topViewController;
    obj.delegate = self;
    }
```

Comment: Great it works!  Good tip on the alloc.  I just knew I didn't want to init it.

Comment: what if the storyboard is a splitview -> navigation controller -> view?  This doesn't work: xmlListofItems *obj = (xmlListofItems *)self.splitViewController.navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject;

Comment: @iDEV, you really need to think about your controller structure, and how your controllers relate to each other -- this is very important basic knowledge about iOS programming that you must learn. I've updated my answer to show you how to do this, but you need to do some studying to learn this stuff.